# Variable parts of hidden layers in a network

Tags: neural-networks

my question is about a variable output or some parts of a net which can vary. For example a flag would direct which output (or some part of a net) is to choose. That means that I have different hidden layers and with means of a flag it will be decided which is to take. Is there some examples available (I have begun to work with pytorch), could you provide someone.

here a small illustration:

[image]

---

the same discussion on pytorch forum

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/variable-parts-of-hidden-layers-in-a-network/45938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two easy options:

- Create two different optimizers, the first will optimize based on the loss at the output for the first branch of your network and will only update the weights in that part of the network. The second will do so only at the second branch of your network.
- Use masks to decide which part of the output is taken into account in the loss (ie multiply the relevant outputs with ones and the irrelevant output with zeros).  You will then only backpropagate through the relevant part of your network.